# IUNavigationController loading more viewControllers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

Not a Noob as yesterday, but still green.
I have a UITabbarcontoller and a IUNavigationController they seem to work fine. I have a UITableviewController  to which I loads my NSMutable array. The user clicks a cell and didSelectRowAtIndexPath xib is loaded onto the stack.  I have a 'Learn More' button on the current xib.  I've tried a few approaches to load a newer xib when the 'Learn More' button is pressed but have failed.  Im thinking it has to do with the Navigation Controller? Do I need to import the navigationcontroller to every ViewControllerSubclass I make? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one calls:

`[self navigationController] pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES]`

to push a new controller onto the view stack. So when the Learn More is pressed, you create a new controller (`-initWithNibName:bundle:`) and load it using that. Be sure to release the new controller.

Look at the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more.